# Using compareTo function in a generic class in Java causes [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Comparable

Tags: java, generics, comparable

I'm facing an exception: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Comparable; while I try to use the compareTo function in my generic class.

Here is my code and I'm facing this issue in the function of insert():

```
public class BinaryTreeArray<T extends Comparable<T>>{
T[] array;
int level, count;
final int capacity;

public BinaryTreeArray(int size)
{
    capacity=size;
    array=(T[]) new Object[capacity];

    for(int i=0; i<capacity; i++)
        array[i]=null;
}

public BinaryTreeArray(T val, int size) //val is the root in this case 
{
    capacity=size;
    array=(T[]) new Object[capacity];
    array[0]=val;
    count=0;

    for(int i=1; i<capacity; i++)
        array[i]=null;
}

public void insert(T x)
{
int currentIndex = 0;
System.out.println("Adding: "+x);
while(true) {
    if(array[currentIndex]==null)
    {
        array[currentIndex]=x;
        System.out.println(" Inserted at index: "+currentIndex);
        break;
    }
    else if(array[currentIndex].compareTo(x)<=0) 
    {
        if(array[currentIndex] == x){
            System.out.println("ERROR!-- Repeating element" );
            break;
        }else
        System.out.print(" Right ");
        currentIndex =(2*currentIndex) + 2;
    }
    else if(array[currentIndex].compareTo(x)>=0)
    {
         if(array[currentIndex] == x){
            System.out.println( "ERROR!-- Repeating element");
            break;
        }else
        System.out.println(" Left ");
        currentIndex=1+(2 * currentIndex);
    }

  }
 }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Show us the full stacktrace, and show us *which* line is causing the error, since the line numbers in the stacktrace is of no use to us.

Comment: I'm using Stack Overflow for the first time, and i don't know how to highlight a particular line. However, inside the function of insert(), compareTo() is being used twice, and I'm getting exceptions for both of them.

Comment: Edit the question and **show us the full stacktrace**.

Comment: Note that you don't need to assign null to all the array elements. Array elements are set to the default value automatically, and the default value of a reference type is null.

Comment: @mysticgirl there's no magic: just add `// THIS LINE` at the appropriate place in the code.

Comment: You can simplify body of the the `BinaryTreeArray(T val, int size)` constructor to: `this(size); insert(val);` - the question must then be asked, though, why provide this constructor at all, rather than just have the user call that constructor and that method themselves? That constructor seems superfluous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the erasure of `T` is `Comparable`, not `Object`, you can't create an `Object[]` and cast it to a `T[]`.

Create a `Comparable[]` instead.

```
array=(T[]) new Comparable[capacity];
```

---

However, you don't really need to constrain your class to naturally comparable types: if you also pass a `Comparator<? super T>` to the constructor, and store that in a field to use when you compare elements, you can accept any type.

```
array[currentIndex].compareTo(x)
```

Would become

```
comparator.compare(array[currentIndex], x)
```

That would remove the upper bound `extends Comparable<T>` from `T`, and allow your `Object[]` array creation to work.